# image in slider preview is repeating

Tags: html, css, image, slider, repeat

May i know how to solve this problem? It is html and css files.
the images are inside the html and the css playing the rules of the slider.
I had made `max-width:100%` at css. The thumb `img` is responsive perfectly at the mobile and desktop device, but the slider preview is repeating the same images and it is not responsive.

css file:

```
#sliderFrame{ 
    max-width:100%; /*the tumb img and frame get responsive perfectly */
    margin:0 auto; /*center-aligned*/
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
    padding:20px;
    background:#191919;
    border:2px solid #999;
    border-radius:6px;

#slider, #slider div.sliderInner {
    max-width:100%;height:640px;} /* when i set to 100% the slide display the image repeating */
```

[sample of the slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3wgo.jpg)

Comment: Please post your code into a snippet so we can see what happens

Comment: why after margin:0 auto you overwrite the margin left and right? is the image a background image?

Comment: margin left and right, give a little space of left and right of the slider. please click the <sample of the slider>, it preview this way... the image display repeating. how to solve this problem? to avoid repeating image in slider. thank you.

Comment: Yes, but you use margin :0 auto; it means margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; and center it. try to remove the 2 addictional margins. Also show us the relevant html code. You give us too less data to recreat your problem

Comment: if i remove the margin left and right, there is no space at the left and right sides... :)

Comment: anyone help me to solve the problem? so the image display at slider not repeating... please help...

Comment: ok you can write margin: 0 50px; For the repeating image please give more information . Do you use a js? what is your html code? Please create a jsfiddle with your slider so we can see it in action and help you. If the image is in the background plase check if you have a repeated background

Comment: how to post the code in a snippet?

Comment: i am not familiar at stackoverflow site.

Comment: You can read [mcve] or use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: How do you display slider image? Is it div with image as its background in css? Is it image tag with image as its src?